# To seed the data from production into the developer sandbox using SandboxPostCopy interface

Tags: apex, sandbox, data, sandboxpostcopy

I don't have much experience in the creation of sandboxes. I have a requirement to seed some data from Prod into the sandbox using `SandboxPostCopy` interface. Is there any way I can do that using SOQL's and `SandboxPostCopy` interface? If yes, can a sample be provided so that I get an idea on how to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Create an Apex class that implements this interface (SandboxPostCopy). Specify your class during sandbox creation. After your sandbox is created, the [runApexClass(context)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm#apex_System_SandboxPostCopy_methods) method in your class runs using the automated process user’s permissions.

Refer this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm#apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy_Example) which show a simple implementation of the SandboxPostCopy interface and a test for that implementation. To test your SandboxPostCopy implementation, use the System.Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript() method.

Reference :- [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm)

You can also refer this [blog](https://www.salesforceben.com/auto-populate-salesforce-sandboxes-with-sample-records/)

Comment: This answer misses what is probably the most important part, "seeding data from production".

Comment: Yes, Derek. Need some code for seeding the data from Prod.